# how to create navbar scrolling/swipe horizontal width cordova?

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

Well i need create a "category list" with multiples items for a cordova app.
The logic says "simple, create a HTML list", but my list dont work fine because sometime this make it "crazy".

**This is i want(swipe navbar):**

[image]
[image]

**And this is the problem(when i trigger "swipe", *some times* this move all page):**

[image]

**And this is de CSS:**

```
.menu-category{position:relative;width:100%;display:block;overflow:hidden;}
.menu-category  ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
.menu-category  ul li {margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;float:left;}
.menu-category  ul li a {margin:0;padding:17px 15px;display:block;background-color:#FFFFFF;}
```

**And this is the HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-category">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Green</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pink</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blue</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Red</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Black</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gray</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Yellow</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery (i dont use more it, but i think maybe need more code):**

```
/**
This code is to recalculate the "css width" for <UL> element, and make it easy to use(enable horizontal scrolling)
*/
(function(){
    var nav = $('.menu-category').children('ul');
    var navWidth = 0;
    nav.find('li').each(function(){
        navWidth+=$(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
    nav.css('width', navWidth);
})(jQuery);
```

And, i use cordova with crosswalk, and Bootstrap + jQuery + jQuery mobile

Comment: The swipe of the whole page is mostly a problem with an element which is too wide and giving the body a bigger width. Best would be to open it in browser and inspect the code

Comment: @FrankProvost but i use "overflow:hidden" to prevent this problem...

Comment: indeed you have but there might be some other styles from jquery mobile or bootstrap which overwrite your code. And it would be hard to find out without inspecting or getting more details. EDIT: jQuery mobile could for example increase the width of your elements or some headers by default forcing them again to increase the body length

Comment: we will atleast need to see your full page markup - maybe you can provide a fiddle

Comment: I actually suppose you will need to set the overflow of your page container to hidden

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu-category{
  position:relative;
  width:100vw;
  display:block;
}
.menu-category  ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  display:flex;
  overflow-x:auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
.menu-category  ul li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}
.menu-category  ul li a {
  margin:0;
  padding:17px 15px;
  display:block;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGdbyO

Comment: this work fine! i will lear about display flex and "vw", thanks!